# Facebook Graph API get tagged photo users

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm building a website for my business which utilises the Graph API to use Facebook's own Photo Albums on our website.

One idea I've got is showing a list of people who are tagged in the photo.

I've had a look around and can't find this anywhere so don't know if it isn't possible or I'm just not looking hard enough.

Thank you!

[Picture of idea](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fcgEp.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/photo, section "Edges". There you will find the edge [`tags`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/photo/tags/).

Comment: Thank you! I owe you a beer.